# ionic 3 screen orientation issue in ios application

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I want to lock one of my page to landscape mode it works perfect in android but not in Ios i can not rotate to landscape it still in portrait mode. do i have to change anything in Xcode settings. i do not know what happened exactly.

I have used something like this

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.screenOrientation.lock('landscape');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable it in Xcode. In the `General` tab, look for `Deployment info` and then check the `Landscape Left` and `Landscape Right` checkboxs:

[image]

Comment: I tried with that option but it is device orientation even portrait page also turn to landscape mode. any other solution.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain with more details what's happening on your app when selecting both checkbox?

Comment: I check both Landscape left and landscape right and then run my application it turns device into landscape mode but i want to turn whenever user enter into particular page it must be landscape but that is device orientation. i don't think it is work for screen orientation.

Comment: Ok, what what happens if after setting this in Xcode, you use the screen orientation cordova plugin like `this.screenOrientation.lock('landscape');`?

Comment: after setting this in xcode then whole device turn to landscape mode. I am using cordova and ionic native plugins.

Comment: But do you also keep the Portrait checkbox checked, right?

Comment: No i checked only landscape right and left and i also verify with everything unchecked.

Comment: But you need to check all the options to allow both portrait and landscape modes. And then use the plugin to lock the mode you want in a given page

Comment: Hello sebafereas, i test with all checked options but no luck did you tested it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :( I used it in one app, where we needed to allow both portrait and landscape modes, but some pages where locked to allow portrait mode only. And it worked just like that...

Comment: My problem got solved with reinstall cordova plugin screen orientation. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

this.ScreenOrientation.lock( this.ScreenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Cordova (I use DevExtreme) with  this.**screenOrientation**.lock('landscape') but now use **screen.orientation.lock**('landscape');

This is what I use Plug + Code.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" />

screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
screen.orientation.unlock();
```

Comment: I am using with ionic native i don't know how to use with cordova plugin directly can you please explain some more.

Comment: U Rock, the this.screenOrientation.lock() in your code snippet is basically supported in Web Sites and MDN says "it is experimental" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation  I have that in one of my mobile apps, but in another one it does not work. So I used the Cordova Plug-in. (IMO I try to use that route in my mobile apps). Even with Ionic you can add Cordova Plugins http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/how-to-use-cordova-plugins-with-your-creator-app